# IF statement (checking for a string in a list) behave weirdly

Tags: python, list

This will probably be a dumb question, but why does this piece of code behave like this?

```
>>> test = ['aaa','bbb','ccc']
>>> if 'ddd' or 'eee' in test:
...     print True
... 
True
>>>
```

I was expecting nothing printed on the stdio, because none of the strings in the IF statement are in the list.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`if 'ddd' or 'eee' in test`

is evaluated as:

`if ('ddd') or ('eee' in test)`:

as a non-empty string is always `True`, so `or` operations short-circuits and returns `True`.

```
>>> bool('ddd')
True
```

To solve this you can use either:

`if 'ddd' in test or 'eee' in test:`

or `any`:

`if any(x in test for x in ('ddd', 'eee'))`:

Answer (score 4):

Your test should be

```
if 'ddd' in test or 'eee' in test:
```

In the code you currently have 'ddd' string is evaluated as boolean and since it is not empty its bool value is True

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something here:

`if 'ddd' or 'eee' in test:`

is equivalent to:

`if ('ddd') or ('eee' in test):`

And thus that will always be True, because `'ddd'` is considered True.

---

You want:

```
if any(i in test for i in ('ddd', 'eee')):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> if 'ddd'
...     print True
```

will print

```
True
```

So you should write :

```
>>> if 'ddd' in test or 'eee' in test:
...     print True
```

in order to get the result you want.