# Python Script not Working def

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

The code below keeps skipping the "TryAgainQuestion()" function:::: I Realy need some help!!! It is becoming annoying

```
    import time
    ranname = "0"

def AskForName():
    ranname = "1"
    name = input("Please enter your name: ")
    print("--------------------")
    print("  .:: ",name," ::.")
    print("--------------------")
    print("     ")
    time.sleep(2)
    Start()

def TryAgainQuestion():
    tryagain = input("Do you want to try again? (Y or N): ")
    if (tryagain == "y" or "Y"):
        AskForName()

    else:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Made By: Daniel Parker")

def Start():
    if (ranname == "1"):
        TryAgainQuestion()

    if (ranname == "0"):
        AskForName()
Start()
```

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: You can't change `ranname` in `AskForName`; it's instead treated as a local variable of `AskForName`. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588317/python-function-global-variables

Comment: If your tutors don't know what's wrong here you might want to consider finding a better educational institution.

Comment: Also, `tryagain == "y" or "Y"` probably doesn't do what you want it to do. Try `tryagain in ["y", "Y"]`.

Comment: And the school tutors didn't mention the unnecessary use of parentheses or the very non-Pythonic naming convention either? Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355810/if-statement-checking-for-a-string-in-a-list-behave-weirdly

Comment: Learnign python, I think you have a serious problem. I mean, your school tutors certainly does.

Comment: @aIKid, yes, the OP has a serious problem - his/her school -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested and said by @georgesl it's scope problem (namespace)

Please read [this](http://bytebaker.com/2008/07/30/python-namespaces/) guide, i'm attaching a working code by a class:

```
import time

class myClass():

    def __init__(self):
        self.ranname = "0"

    def AskForName(self):
        self.ranname = "1"
        name = raw_input("Please enter your name: ")
        print("--------------------")
        print("  .:: ", name, " ::.")
        print("--------------------")
        print("     ")
        time.sleep(2)
        self.Start()

    def TryAgainQuestion(self):
        tryagain = raw_input("Do you want to try again? (Y or N): ")
        if (tryagain == "y"):
            self.AskForName()

        else:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Made By: Daniel Parker")

    def Start(self):
        if self.ranname == "1":
            self.TryAgainQuestion()

        if self.ranname == "0":
            self.AskForName()

def main():

    myclass = myClass()
    myclass.Start()

   #end of main

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks very much, your help is very appricated!!

Answer (score 2):

It's a scope problem : the `ranmame` at the second line is not the same as the one in the `AskForName` function. You need to  add `global ranname` at the beginning of the function to update properly.

```
import time
ranname = "0"

def AskForName():
    global ranname
    ranname = "1"
```